# How do you get dnsmasq to specify alternate DNS servers?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dhcp, dnsmasq

I'm working on a network with ~10 kubuntu desktops (and numerous servers and IP phones) and am trying to get dnsmasq to specify another dns server as a failover. I tried using

```
server=192.168.0.90
```

but that just added the single dhcp/dns server to /etc/resolv.conf on my test machine (dynamic IP and freshly rebooted with no lease).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Answered my own question, thanks to [rfc2132](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132)

```
dhcp-option=6,192.168.0.90,192.168.0.98
```

However, RFC2132 specifies option 5 as a list of name servers and option 6 as a list of domain name servers, and I'm not sure what the difference is. Either way, option 6 put them correctly as

```
nameserver 192.168.0.90
nameserver 192.168.0.98
```

in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Unfortunately /etc/resolv.conf refreshes after restart

Comment: @FeridMovsumov use `server=8.8.8.8` in /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Comment: @Tek Google needs to know everything?

Comment: @ceving If not google then your ISP

Comment: For posterity: `dnsmasq --help dhcp`

Comment: This is the respective textual option which I prefer over opaque numbers like `6`: `dhcp-option=option:dns-server,...`

Comment: DHCP option 5 is for IEN 116 style 'trivial name server daemon' (tnamed), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPA_Host_Name_Server_Protocol . Wasn't aware of its existance. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 10):

Posting as a separate answer rather than a comment on yours because that way I can use links.

Option 5 is for [IEN 116](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien116.txt) nameservers — a ridiculously obsolete protocol that Jon Postel [wanted dead](http://www-mice.cs.ucl.ac.uk/multimedia/misc/tcp_ip/8602.mm.www/0096.html) over twenty years ago.  Solaris still [supports it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/tnamed-1m.html), but won't in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to set your dnsmasq server to be the DNS server for DHCP, and use `/etc/resolv.conf` on the dnsmasq server to specify your list of DNS servers. That way you can easily change DNS (and set aliases) without having to wait for DHCP renewal - just either restart or `kill -HUP` dnsmasq to reload the config.

Comment: Andrew, 'kill' command expects process identifier not process name.
You should use either kill -HUP `pidof dnsmasq` or killall -HUP dnsmasq .